# Unable to locate element using ID and Css selector methods

Tags: selenium-webdriver

//  
//    United States

```
copy selector = #ddlCountries
Select drpCountries = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("ddlCountries")));
drpCountries.selectByValue("999");
```

I keep getting this error no such element: Unable to locate element: `{"method":"id","selector":"ddlCountries"}`

Answer (score 0):

Call using SelectOptionInList("ddlCountries","999");

```
public IWebDriver SelectOptionInList(string elementID, string optionValue)
    {
        SelectElement ElementSelect = new SelectElement(driver.FindElement(By.Id(elementID)));
        IList<IWebElement> ElementList = ElementSelect.Options;
        int ElementCount = ElementList.Count;

        for (int i = 0; i < ElementCount; i++)
        {
            string elementText = ElementList.ElementAt(i).Text;
            if (elementText.Equals(optionValue))
            {
                ElementList.ElementAt(i).Click();
                Console.WriteLine("Option " + optionValue + "Clicked");
                return driver;
            } 
            else if(elementText.Contains(optionValue))
            { 
                ElementList.ElementAt(i).Click();
                Console.WriteLine("Option " + optionValue + "Clicked");
                return driver;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Option " + optionValue + " Not Found Under Element with ID: " + elementID);
            }
        }
        return driver;
    }
```